# Need to add a script to change a filename to a installshield 2010 installer

Tags: installation, installshield-2010

I need to add a script that will change the name of two files in my install shield 2010 build.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you found a way of doing this ?

Comment: No I just ended up changing the filenames manually.  BTW I think if you upvote a question it increases the chances of other people seeing it/answering it.